Llenar un DataGrid con el resultado de un Stored Procedure del que desconozco las columnas en WPF
Hace rato que no hago nada en WPF, pero ahorita tengo un requerimiento, necesito mostrar el resultado de un Stored Procedure seleccionado de una lista, en un Data Grid, para que luego el usuario copie desde allí esa información y se la lleve a Excel
Como las columnas del resultado no son fijas, varían según el SP que se esté ejecutando, pues no puedo definirlas en el xaml del DataGrid, así que lo defino así:
<DataGrid x:Name="grdResultadoReporte" AutoGenerateColumns="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1200" Height="460" 
                CanUserResizeColumns="True"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding ResultadoReporte,                             
    Mode=TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    Source={StaticResource ReportesGerencialesVM}, 
    NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
    NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,
    NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
            ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
            IsReadOnly="True" 
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            CanUserSortColumns="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
</DataGrid>

Pero ahora no sé cómo definir el ResultadoReporte... como una ObservableCollection? de qué tipo?
Ya tengo los resultados del SP y los muestro uno a uno en pantalla:
using (SqlConnection cn = myConexion())
{
    cn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_ReporteSeleccionado.NombreReporte, cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    foreach (var item in _ParametrosReportes)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.NombreParametro, item.ValorParametro);
    }

    cmd.CommandTimeout = 100000;

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Mensaje = new wMensaje("Aviso", dr[i].ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
                Mensaje.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Mensaje = new wMensaje("Aviso", "NO HAY INFORMACIÓN PARA LOS CRITERIOS DE SELECCIÓN DEFINIDOS " + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Mensaje.ShowDialog();
    }

¿cómo los paso a mi DataGrid?

probaste lo que decis? deberia funcionar si la grilla esta para que autogenere las columnas...

Puedo barrer el resultado del stored procedure, pero no sé cómo asignarlo como una lista de datos para poder ponerlo en el xaml como ItemSource y que se autogeneren allí las columnas y la lista de datos

Genera una observable collection y llenala con los datos del SP, y usa esa lista como objeto del binding de los datos...

El tema es que el resultado no va a ser fijo, seleccionan un SP a ejecutar, y ese podría tener en total 3 columnas de datos y X registros... pero si seleccionan otro al ejecutarlo ese podría traer 6 columnas de datos y Y registros, y así, entonces no tengo una Clase fija para definir un ObservableCollection de ese tipo y asignarlo como ItemSource de mi Datagrid... espero haberme explicado bien...

no sé cómo pasar el resultado de mi SqlDataReader a una colección de datos que pueda ser el ItemSource de mi DataGrid...

No tengo para hacerte un ejemplo aca a mano (y me llevaria un rato)... pero proba lo siguiente.. podes crear las columnas en tiempo de ejecucion, y luego tu observable collection tendria que tener una lista que contiene una lista de objetos (lista para filas, y en cada una, una lista para las columnas) de esa forma podrias hacer el binding. Seguro hay otras formas tambien.. le podrias pasar directamente un datatable ya cargado con el resultado de tu SP y saldria funcionando. Podrias usar un ORM con datos dinamicos... mira por ejemplo por aca https://stackoverflow.com/a/64340674/73749

Tienes que crear una clase que permita objetos dinámicos, para esto debes extender de DynamicObject, además quizás te sirva implementar la interfaz INotifyPropertyChanged.
La clase debería ser algo asi:
public class ItemSP : DynamicObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private readonly IDictionary<string, object> Campos = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return Campos.Keys;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = this[binder.Name];
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        this[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public object this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (Campos.ContainsKey(columnName))
            {
                return Campos[columnName];
            }
            return null;
          
        }
        set
        {

            if (!Campos.ContainsKey(columnName))
            {
                Campos.Add(columnName, value);
                OnPropertyChanged(columnName);
            }
            else if (Campos[columnName] != value)
            {
                Campos[columnName] = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(columnName);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

Además, te recomiendo mapear las cabeceras con un nombre legible según cada procedimiento de almacenado
public string[] Cabeceras(string SP_name) => SP_name switch
{
    "Nombre del SP 1" => ["primera cabecera", "segunda Cabecera"],
    "Nombre del SP 2" => ["primera cabecera", "segunda Cabecera"],
    _ => []
};

Y luego cargas los datos así:
if (dr.HasRows)
{
   //Creamos una colección para guardar los datos
   //Aquí se crea una vez por cada consulta, pero bien puedes tener una global y solo borrar los datos contenidos cada vez que la renuevas
    ObservableCollection<ItemSP> Rows = new ObservableCollection<ItemSP>();
                  
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        //creamos un objeto dinamico
        ItemSP objeto = new ItemSP();
        for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            //asignamos propiedades y valores al objeto
            //a las propiedades les llamé "item0", "item1", etc
            objeto["item" + i] = dr[i];
        }
        Rows.Add(objeto);
    }
}
var cabeceras = Cabeceras(_ReporteSeleccionado.NombreReporte);

dataGrid.ItemsSource = Rows; //bindiamos la colección con el datagris. Esto no es necesario si la colección es global
dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < cabeceras.Length; i++)
{
    //creamos las cabeceras con su nombres y establecemos a cada columna la propiedad contra la cual "bindea"
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = cabeceras[i], Binding = new Binding("item" + i) });
}


Estuve unos días fuera, muchas gracias por tu aporte Yussef, voy a intentarlo

Yussef, veo en una parte en la que haces referencia directa a los nombres de los SP, pero no los conozco, la lista de los SP disponibles, me la traigo en tiempo de ejecución consultando el sys.objects de la base de datos SQL a la que se haya conectado la aplicación (también la lista de parámetros que ocupa el SP seleccionado), así que puede variar la BD y obviamente pueden variar los SP disponibles...

@Cyndy No hay problema con eso, tu sacas la lista de donde sea. Lo importante es la clase del primer código, que te permite crear un objeto dinámico y bindiable

uff, es la primera vez que veo esto DynamicObject... y la primera línea private readonly IDictionary<string, object?> Campos = new Dictionary<string, object?>(); me marca en el = new, el error "El tipo 'object' debe ser un tipo de valor distinto de null para poder utilizarlo como parámetro 'T' en el tipo o método genérico 'System.Nullable' "   :(

@Cyndy Versión de .net??

versión .NET 4.5

@Cyndy Ahí el problema este código es para la 8,0. Cambia todos los object? por object (sin ? el final) igualmente con el string? de la última función. Más tarde actualizo el código (ahora estoy algo ocupado)

Yussef, ya hice los cambios que me sugeriste... pero ahora me marca un error en la parte de public object this[string columnName]... en las dos partes donde se usa el TryGetValue: TryGetValue(columnName, out object valor) marca el error: "La mejor coincidencia de método sobrecargado para 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object>.TryGetValue(string, out object)' tiene algunos argumentos no válidos"...

@Cyndy He editado la clase, me avisas cualquier cosa y para la próxima pregunta, favor agregar la versión de .net.

la versión de .net que estoy usando es la 4.5... ya hice los ajustes que me comentas, y ya funcionó!! la información ya la veo correcta en el ViewModel según la colección de datos con la clase dinámica, el único detalle es que no se como configurar el DataGrid en xaml, porque al bindear la colección de datos, en el view solo me presenta la cantidad de renglones en blanco según la cantidad de elementos de la colección...

Yussef, muchas gracias, de momento con tu aporte ya solucioné mi requerimiento, no lo pude desplegar en el DataGrid en pantalla, pero el fin ultimo como quiera era copiar el resultado a una hoja de excel, entonces me brinqué el paso de mostrarlo a pantalla y directamente de la colección de datos de mi clase dinámica, lo mandé escribir a excel y ya funcionó correctamente. Muchas gracias!

Lo primero que necesita es una clase para mapear lo que devuelve el sp, podria ser algo como esto:
public class ColumnsData : Dictionary<string, object>
{
   //donde string es el nombre de la columna y objecto el tipo de dato devuelto (varchar,int , etc) 
}

En el while que lee los datos de la bd va creando instancias (while (dr.Read())) de ColumnsData, y una vez que obtiente los datos en una Lista de ColumnsData entonces se los pasa como Source a el datagrid:
grdResultadoReporte.DataContext = rowDataList;


Estuve unos días fuera, muchas gracias por tu aporte Richard Víquez Pérez, voy a intentarlo
